# Important and Useful tools for Developing Android Applications

Tags: android

I'm new in `Android Development`. I know Eclipse is the first thing I need to start.

Can you list any useful and very needed tools for `Android Application Development`?

Comment: I just have published article on the same so thought to share: [Useful tools for android application development](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-android-part-7-useful-tools/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

That's the only thing you need. Framework, Eclipse plugin, adb, ddms, emulator, all in one place.

UPDATE: Some tutorials sites I have in my bookmarks to get you starting:

http://androidcore.com/google-android-programming-tutorials.html

http://www.hascode.com/2010/04/first-steps-on-android-creating-a-simple-todo-app/

http://sites.google.com/site/androidappcourse/labs

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

Comment: thanks @typo.pl, @Aleadam. Sorry!, It's not enough to me. :). I need extra tools, i.e design, testing, and some others related tools.

Comment: You have the emulator to test and ddms to monitor the device. There are a few gui builders but I never liked them. What are you specifically looking for?

Comment: The Eclipse IDE includes unit testing, application testing, and a refactoring tool. It would be nice if it shipped with version control built in.

Comment: @JAL true, but I guess you can use github, but then you can't have both a free (as in beer) service and a not free (as in speech) app

Answer (score 1):

All you need for `Android Application Development` is:

1. [The Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) including the ADT Plugin for Eclipse and adb tool
2. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)
3. If you're developing on Windows and want to debug an app on an actual Android device, you may need a USB driver, [PDANet](http://www.junefabrics.com/android/download.php) has USB drivers for several popular Android device makers. Otherwise the Google USB driver may work or check with your Android device maker's website.